# Add image to a Wordpress megamenu

Tags: wordpress, image, menu, megamenu

I would like to add an image in a menu tab of the ShadePro theme without adding any plugin (see https://www.glofox.com/). I asked to the support, they told me that it was possible by passing through the megamenus. I did my research but I did not find any solution without using plugins. How can I do this?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Default WordPress menu does not have image functionality, So you have to use a plugin. There are many mega menu plugins is available you can use one of them and follow the proper plugin configure guideline.

A few mega menu plugins links are:

1.a) https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-megamenu/

1.b) https://demo.themeum.com/wordpress/wp-megamenu/

2. https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-add-image-icons-with-navigation-menus-in-wordpress/

Comment: Thanks, but I want to do this without any plugin. So, it's not possible in my case ?

Comment: @Sn0w: It's possible but you have to add more code in functions.php. if you don't have to use the plugin you can install any mega menu plugin and check its functionality. if you like, then you can copy the plugin code to our function.php and then remove the installed plugin.  if possible install mega menu plugin in other wp sites and copy code from where to our main site. if possible rename the class/method name.